# how to repeat column names with a specific frequency in R

Tags: r

I have a 10x5 matrix. Each of the five columns, is named.

I need to create a vector like this:

```
c( rep(colnames(mymatrix)[1], dim(mymatrix)[1]),
   rep(colnames(mymatrix)[2], dim(mymatrix)[1]),
...
  rep(colnames(mymatrix)[5], dim(mymatrix)[1]))
```

However, what if I have a varying number of columns? How do I automate this without using a for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: what's your rule? r can't guess how many times you want each repeated

Comment: Have you actually run this code yet?

Comment: Yes, so my matrix right now is 10x5. I want a vector of length 50. The first 10 entries are the first column name. The next 10 entries are the next column name. Etc. I need to automate this for a variable number of column names and rows

Comment: @user1357015 - That last comment should be in your question. It's a good explanation of what you want, which should always be in the questions you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `each` argument to `rep`:

```
rep(colnames(mymatrix), each=dim(mymatrix)[1])
```

To see how this works, you can try:

```
v = c("h", "e", "l", "l", "o")
rep(v, each=5)
#  [1] "h" "h" "h" "h" "h" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e" "l" "l" "l" "l" "l" "l" "l" "l" "l"
# [20] "l" "o" "o" "o" "o" "o"
```